# Enable extended desktop on Windows 7 Starter?

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, display, extended-desktop

How do I enable `extended desktop` in Windows 7 Starter?

I don't want to have to upgrade to Windows 7 Home Premium to get this feature.  Any ideas?

Comment: What, specifically, do you mean by "Extended desktop" ?

Do you want multiple monitor support (with one big desktop) or to you want multiple desktops (ie virtual desktops) on a single monitor?

Comment: my original desktop, start menu etc remains on laptop screen, but i can also put movie on big lcd screen. windows 7 starter only have duplicate option

Comment: I think there is a patch for it just none of us found it yet. I had the same question in my head. That being said, You cannot use ProPresenter for presenting on windows 7 starter. That also means you can't use presenter view in PowerPoint either. Those are what I were trying to figure out. However, you can use a single monitor in windows 7 starter. You could use only your other monitor or TV Screen. But that doesn't allow you to use ProPresnter or PowerPoint Presenter view.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry. [There are certain features that are just not a part of Windows 7 Starter](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows/archive/b/windows7/archive/2009/05/29/let-s-talk-about-windows-7-starter.aspx), and they can't just be enabled. The other editions have more features, which is why they're more expensive.  Among the missing features are:

- Multiple monitor support
- Aero Glass
- Desktop personalization
- DVD playback

Comment: i know about limitations, im interested in bypassing them. i will not buy new windows 7 just because it will add extended desktop feature.